# How to disable Ionic2 livereload

Tags: ionic2

I need to disable ionic2 livereload. I am using the following command to run an app.There is no file like ionic.config.js

```
ionic serve
```

Answer (score 1):

Help for ionic serve. More info: ionic -h

```
ionic serve [options] … Start a local development server for app dev/testing 
[–consolelogs|-c] … Print app console logs to Ionic CLI
[–serverlogs|-s] … Print dev server logs to Ionic CLI
[–port|-p] … Dev server HTTP port (8100 default)
[–livereload-port|-r] … Live Reload port (35729 default)
[–nobrowser|-b] … Disable launching a browser
[–nolivereload] … Do not start live reload
```

Look at the last switch.